# How to close UAModalPanel manually

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

i have downloaded one nice sample code [UAModalPanel](http://code.coneybeare.net/uamodalpanel-an-open-source-modal-panel-alter). i have implemented it in my project, if we tap segment control's first index it will open the UAModalPanel. i could successfully implemented this one.

But if we select second or third index in segment control i need to close the UAModalPanel How can i achieve this. if anyone knows guide me?

[image] 
**if we tap the segment control below will be called**

```
   -(void)navBarSegmentCntrl_tapped
{
if(navBarSegmentCntrl.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
{

    UAExampleModalPanel *modalPanel = [[UAExampleModalPanel alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds title:@"dfg" ];



    [self.view addSubview:modalPanel];

    // Show the panel from the center of the screen
    [modalPanel showFromPoint:self.view.center];



}
else if(navBarSegmentCntrl.selectedSegmentIndex==1)
{
    [UAmodal hide];  //UAmodal allocated in view didload//
    imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = 
    UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES];   
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the object that you are calling `show` is not the same one your are calling `hide`. You should declare it in your interface file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    UAModalPanel *myModalPanel;
}
```

And then, when you show it in `navBarSegmentCntrl_tapped` method, you init this `myModalPanel`  (remember you don't need to do `UAModalPanel *myModalPanel` again, once you already set it up, and your view controller is "already aware of the object". You just do `myModalPanel = [[UAModalPanel alloc] init....`).

Then, to hide it, just call `[myModalPanel hide];`.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I tried this way but its not working. hide method called but ModalPanel is not hiding. do i need to set any delegate?

Comment: i allocated UAModalPanel only

Comment: modalPanel object is for UAExampleModalPanel and UAmodal is for UAModalPanel

Comment: But why don't you use the same? Did you try the way I wrote?

Comment: I did not use same. is there any mistake in code which is added by me? i tried your way its not working.